# What is the facebook query language object ID

Tags: java, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

I am trying to query the `page_active_users` from Insights with the FQL. It tells me I need an Object ID. My Question is, what is that?

This is my query `SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id = '34704290384/insights/page_consumptions/week' AND period = 604800 AND end_time= end_time_date('2013-12-01') AND metric = 'page_active_users'`

i got the objectID from this

```
34704290384/insights/page_consumptions/week
```

I tried just the numbers but I always just get this from Facebook:

```
{
"data": [
]
}
```

I used the restFB library for java to query the entire insight and I got views from it so they do exist.

What is the error?

Comment: try to use `34704290384` instead `34704290384/insights/page_consumptions/week` as `object_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to query `SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE URL='facebook.com/insertmypagehere`